# Invalid name that I didn't actually write

Tags: ms-access-2016

I'm attempting to use a MS Access query update to take the value of one field, the value of another in a different table, multiply them together, and then put the result in a third table. When just doing it as a SELECT statement, the statement works perfectly fine - the table output is exactly what is expected. However, when specifying an update query, it tells me the name is invalid, and the invalid name is not the one I wrote in.

The error:

> 'PO Lines.Quantityity]*[Item Master].[Purchased Price]' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

The statement:

`EXPR: [PO Lines].[Quantity]*[Item Master].[Purchased Price]`

(with Update To as `[PO Lines].[Price]` and Table as `PO Lines`). If any more information is needed, please inform me; however, I wouldn't even know where to begin. All fields exist - as I said, the statement worked perfectly well as a Select.

Comment: update your question and add  all the query code please

Comment: Saving calculated (dependent) data is usually a bad idea. Save raw data and calculate when result needed. If you need to save a value because prices can change over time, then save the item price into [PO Lines], not the calculated extended price.  Why is a third table even involved?

Comment: `'PO Lines.Quantityity]` indeed is not a valid name. Misspelled too.